# Strip all images with data.replace?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm using a script to retrieve content from an external website, and the date is returned with certain elements stripped out so that they don't interfere with the page I'm pulling the data to. However, when I view my page with the error console open, I am receiving 404s on all images. Is there anyway I can strip out all the images from the script so that I'm just getting the text (which is still in its formatted tags)?

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var container = $('#target');

    function doAjax(url) {
        if (url.match('^http')) {
            $.getJSON("http://query.yahooapis.com/v1/public/yql?" 
            + "q=select%20*%20from%20html%20where%20url%3D%22" 
            + encodeURIComponent(url) 
            + "%22&format=xml'&callback=?", 
            function (data) {
                if (data.results[0]) {
                    var fullResponse = $(filterData(data.results[0])),
                        justTable = fullResponse.find("table");
                    container.append(justTable);
                } else {
                    var errormsg = '<p>Error: could not load the page.</p>';
                    container.html(errormsg);
                }
            });
        } else {
            $('#target').load(url);
        }
    }
    function filterData(data) {
        data = data.replace(/<?\/body[^>]*>/g, '');
        data = data.replace(/[\r|\n]+/g, '');
        data = data.replace(/<--[\S\s]*?-->/g, '');
        data = data.replace(/<noscript[^>]*>[\S\s]*?<\/noscript>/g, '');
        data = data.replace(/<script[^>]*>[\S\s]*?<\/script>/g, '');
        data = data.replace(/<script.*\/>/, '');
        return data;
    }
    doAjax('mywebsite');
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Option 1:**

You can strip the images by adding this line to `filterData()` function:

```
data = data.replace(/<img[^>]*>/g, '');
```

This will replace all strings starting with `<img` and then containing zero or more characters other than `>` with an empty string.

**Option 2:**

You can use jQuery to remove the elements. Insert this before `container.append()`:

```
justTable.find("img").remove();
```

This will find all `img` elements inside the table and remove them.

**Alternative:**

Some images are not available because their URL is relative. If you have `<img src="logo.png">` on `http://example.com/page.html` then browser is loading the image from `example.com/logo.png`. If you include the same `<img>` tag to your page  `http://own.com/my.html` then browser will try to load `own.com/logo.png`.

You can fix this issue by changing the `src` attribute of the images to include the domain you retrieved the page from.

Example (not fully tested, may need modifications):

```
// copy everything for url except the string after last "/" character
// so if url == http://example.com/page.html then path == http://example.com/
var path = url.match("(.+/)[^/]+$")[1];

// modify all local images (value of src attribute not starting with "http://")
justTable.find('img').not('[src^="http://"]').attr('src', function() { 
   return path + $(this).attr('src');
 });
```

Comment: @Charlie: Added explanation and a alternative proposal in case you want those images loaded correctly :).